# Migration from create-react-app to Vite, loading variables into window object

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using `Vite 4.3.5` version.

`vite.config.ts` -

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    jsxFactory: "jsx",
  },
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react",
      babel: {
        plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin"],
      },
    }),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
  ],
});
```

`index.html` file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <script type="module" src="/config.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.config = { redirectToLogin, authAppUrl, apiUrl };
    </script>
    <title>Solvo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm running the app with `Vite`, the `window` object don't recognize the properties from `config.js`, I would like to understand what's the `window` object differences between `CRA` to `Vite`, and how can I add vars to the `window` object when using `Vite`

If I'm assigning the vars inside the index.html file, the properties are assigned as expected, but that's not a wanted solution I want to use separate the `config.js` file -

```
    <script>
      const redirectToLogin = true;
      const authAppUrl =
        "https://signin";
      const apiUrl = "https://api";


      window.config = {
        redirectToLogin,
        authAppUrl,
        apiUrl
      };
    </script>
```